# How to make backspace respect tab-stops when there is only preceeding white-space?

Tags: indentation, backspace

When pressing backspace, it deletes a single character, however, I would like it to go back the the previous tab-stop level in the case there is only preceding white-space.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using this function, based on [this answer](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackspaceWhitespaceToTabStop) on the Emacs wiki.

```el
(defun my-backspace-whitespace-to-tab-stop ()
  "Delete whitespace backwards to the next tab-stop, otherwise delete one character."
  (interactive)
  (if (or indent-tabs-mode (use-region-p)
          (> (point)
             (save-excursion
               (back-to-indentation)
               (point))))
      (call-interactively 'backward-delete-char)
    (let ((step (% (current-column) tab-width))
          (pt (point)))
      (when (zerop step)
        (setq step tab-width))
      ;; Account for edge case near beginning of buffer.
      (setq step (min (- pt 1) step))
      (save-match-data
        (if (string-match "[^\t ]*\\([\t ]+\\)$"
                          (buffer-substring-no-properties
                           (- pt step) pt))
            (backward-delete-char (- (match-end 1)
                                     (match-beginning 1)))
          (call-interactively 'backward-delete-char))))))
```